# How to include view specific .less files in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular UI_Router in my project. I want to load specific .less files for specific states. I tried with angular-UI-router-styles, but it didn't work. May be am using less instead of css.

Please check my code. am using angular-ui-router-styles for css adding into the routing. it is working but the styles for the pages are not reflecting.

**index.js**

```
require('jquery/dist/jquery.js');
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
  require('./content/common.css');
require('angular');

require('angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js');
 require('angular-route/angular-route.js');
require('angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js');
require('materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css');
require('angular-ui-router-styles/ui-router-styles.js');
angular.module('adminsuite',['ui.router','ngCookies','uiRouterStyles']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        views:{
            content:{
                templateUrl: 'Login/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController',
                data:{
                    css:"styles/login/login.less"
                }
            },
            footer:{
                templateUrl: 'common/footer.html',
                controller: 'footerController'
            }
        }



    })
    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views:{
            header:{
                templateUrl: 'common/header.html',
                controller: 'headerController'
            },
            content:{
                templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'dashboardController',
                data:{
                    css:"styles/dashboard/dashboard.less"
                }
            },
            footer:{
                templateUrl: 'common/footer.html',
                controller: 'footerController'
            }
        }
    });

    // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================

   });

require('./Login/loginController.js');
 require('./dashboard/dashboardController.js');
 require('./common/headerController.js');
 require('./common/footerController.js');
  require('./services/loginAuthenticationService.js');
 require('./services/UserServices.js');
```

Comment: `LESS` is a css preprocessor. You need to compile to CSS before using in html.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I'm aware of to achieve this would be to use a `Webpack` or similar build. This way you can `require('./state-1.less')` within your component/directive. The idea is that webpack only includes files that are needed. Realistically though, setting up a new compiling tool/task runner is not simple if you've already begun.

There is no issue in providing all css to your application. If switching is your task then you can use `ngclass` to provide different style blocks based on events that occur within in each state.

`The_ehT` is correct, you'll need to provide compiled css if you want to use the desired plugin.